# Category name with total number of product in that category in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

can anyone explain me how to show the category title with the number of product in that category in category archive page like **category 1(10)**

the url is http://www.example.com/product-category/category-1/

Can anyone help me..............
 I have tried this but it display total product of the website. I want only the product in that category

```
<h1><?php woocommerce_page_title(); 


global $woocommerce_loop;
 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category ); 

                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
        ?>  


        </h1>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to solve this

```
<h1><?php woocommerce_page_title(); 



global $wp_query;
// get the query object
$cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();


if($cat_obj)    {
    $category_name = $cat_obj->name;
    $category_desc = $cat_obj->description;
    $category_ID  = $cat_obj->term_id;
}


$term = get_term( $category_ID, 'product_cat' ); 
echo '('. $term->count . ')';


?>      
        </h1>
```

Placed this in "archive-product.php"

Answer (score 2):

To list all the categories along with the product count:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' ); 
foreach( $terms as $term ) 
{
    echo 'Product Category: '
        . $term->name
        . ' - Count: '
        . $term->count;
}
```

If you have a category ID:

```
$term = get_term( CAT_ID, 'product_cat' );   //Replace your category ID here
echo 'Product Category: '
    . $term->name
    . ' - Count: '
    . $term->count;
```

Comment: This echo all the category and its counts. How can I display count of each category with title in each each category archive page ????????

Comment: Try this one, hope it works: 

global $wp_query;

$cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$term = get_term( $cat_obj->term_id, 'product_cat' ); 
 
echo 'Product Category: '
    . $term->name
    . ' - Count: '
    . $term->count;